# Destroying old slick carousel instance each time a user calls its initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, garbage-collection, slick.js

I would like to know if I should destroy my Slick carousel instance before I call it each time on a page where it could be called N+ times?
ex. I have a calendar and each time the user clicks on a date with events, I initialize Slick like this

```
$("#slickEvents").slick({options here})
```

then those events get shown in a slick carousel. If the user clicks on another date with events, I get the new HTML and Slick gets called again. So this could be called N+ times while the user is on that calendar page.
Do I have to worry about Javascript building up instances without releasing them in some garbage collector or should I do a check to see if a Slick instance is initialized first then use the Slick destroy method like this

```
if (slickIsInitialized)
{
    $("#slickEvents").slick('unslick'); destroys the slick instance
}
$("#slickEvents").slick({options here});
```

Slick does have a method called 'getSlick', but I'm not sure how or if I can use it this way

```
$("#slickEvents").slick('getSlick');
```

I also looked for a 'reInit' method but don't see one, only a 'reInit' event, but it doesn't get called each time I instantiate a slick instance, only the init event gets called!

Is there a way to check in the debugger if instances are building up and if they are being released or not? I'm a little new to JS, coming from a C# background

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of your question, yes, there is a way to see memory usage in JS. In the devtools of most browsers there is a JS Profiler (in Chrome it is in the "Performance" tab). [Here's](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/#visualize_memory_leaks_with_timeline_recordings) a brief explanation of how to use it in Chrome as it's what I used in the second half of my answer.

Now, to answer the first part of your question, it appears extra initializations of Slick don't cause memory issues.

[image]
Here's a screenshot from the Chrome debugger of a graph of the JS Heap (a topic too complicated for this answer -- assume it's the total memory usage for our case) where I repeatedly called `$('#object').slick()` on the same DOM object (note I used an ID selector) over a time period of about 10 seconds by clicking on a button. There should have been no other JS activity on this tab.

Each "step" in the graph is a new call to `slick` which is verifiable in the call trace (it's too big to post here since Slick does other initialization, but it shouldn't be hard to verify it yourself). Note that the extra objects are being garbage collected when the "cliffs" occur (the last part stays high because the heap hasn't gotten big enough to trigger another *Major GC* event).

Likewise, if a DOM element becomes inaccessible, the Slick object should also be GC'd. Since Slick is based on a JQuery extension function, it should be GC'd when the element's JQuery object is (as that should be the only reference to it and the DOM element is the only reference to the JQuery instance).

Finally, just in case I'm not reading the question improperly you probably *should* be making new instances of Slick for new DOM elements. I notice you were concerned about creating a new Slick instance for new page elements, but even the library [Demo](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#demos) page does that. Since Slick uses JQuery, you'll want to do this so you don't accidentally cause events to be fired on the wrong elements (such as if you start using the `slickAdd` functions).

P.S.: With regard to the `reInit` event, it seems to be fired whenever DOM manipulation occurs (such as adding a new slide to a carousel or filtering a carousel). It's not actually a reinitialization of any sort (which is somewhat confusing given its name).

Comment: Peter, thanks for the info! This really helps and I tried the memory profiler and see one interesting occurrence. When I click on my calendar day that has events, slick is called and loads the events info into the slides in the dom. If I click again on the same day, which loads the same slick slides and I do this over and over again, no memory build up occurs. But if I click on one day and then another day, then another, etc,etc and look at the profiler, memory does build up. So now I will need to determine if it's something else or Slick. Can you advise on the part in the profiler for this?

Comment: Unfortunately the profiler only shows _total_ memory rather than the memory created by individual calls. Keep in mind that `$('some-selector').slick()` is a factory function (ergo, it creates a new object for each selector used) so I would expect the memory usage to be O(n)  (each selector needs its own object so events can be emitted). As long as the DOM element Slick is attached to is still in the tree, the object will _not_ be GC'd. `unslick` does free memory in my tests, but do consider if it's really necessary. Having the object initialized can help if the browser needs to re-render it.